# Using Twitter Bootstrap-MultiSelect

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I am trying to use Twitter Bootstrap-Multi Select.

The only successful examples use the following format in their html pages.

```
<select id="slYears" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1" >2009</option>
    <option value="2" >2010</option>
    <option value="3" >2011</option>
    <option value="4" >2012</option>
    <option value="5" >2013</option>
</select>
```

My html format looks more like this:

```
@*<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonIds, "Person", new { @class = "col-md-12" })
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.PersonIds, this.Model.People, new { @class = "form-control cascade-organisations" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PeopleIds, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>*@
```

Is there an easy way to implement the two ?

Thankyou

Comment: Simply add select picker to the class.

{@class = "col-md-12" selectpicker"} should work perfectly. Javascript and css links must also be present.